# How to remove mold from cloth upholstery

Tags: mold, furniture, removal

My coach is covered in black mold, Google search shows various suggestions including vinegar, bleach, hydrogen peroxide, rubbing alcohol. Which is the most effective proven method to remove mold without damaging my coach. The covering of the coach can be detached and washed.

Comment: call in a professional, or discard the couch ...black mold is a health hazard

Comment: What sport does he coach?